# 401 unauthorized error when trying to login via console

Tags: javascript, authentication, console.log, http-status-code-401

[image]Suppose,http://www.example.com  is my site and I am trying to login via console
using DOM

```
document.getElementById("username").value = "username";
document.getElementById("password").value = "password";
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].click();
```

I get the following error message. **NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized**.How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are there any hidden fields available in the login form ? may be you are missing those fields . Check those fields and send all those values . One more thing , the click event must submit the **form** , if the other controls are **form controls**

Comment: Yes there are two hidden fields. How to pass those ?
<input name="cval" value="1618824560" type="hidden">
<input name="return_to" value="" type="hidden">

Comment: $("#MyForm").trigger('submit'); submit your form rather than clicking on the button, to submit all the fields of the form

Comment: post your html also .

Comment: if that works , Accept the Answer , for the downvoter.